# How do I pass a run-time variable into a react/webpack module

Tags: symfony, reactjs, variables, webpack, global-variables

I am attempting to convert an Angular 1.x app to React/Redux.

I have been successful and have been quite happy with React and learning it, Redux, etc.  (This is via create-react-app and using the usual dev flow of npm start, etc).  My 'test' app works great and now I am ready to integrate into Symfony replacing the existing Angular app.

But, I have hit a snag.  The front-end is part of a Symfony PHP framework app and I am unsure of the best way to inject or pass a run-time variable from Symfony into the final included compiled webpack react app.

In Angular, it was easy (*{{var1}} and {{var2}} are symfony php variables*) :

```
  [js in Symfony html file]

  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm" 
       ng-init="vm.init('{{var1}}', '{{var2}}')">
        <rendered-stuff>
        </rendered-stuff>
  </div>
```

However, being very new to React and Webpack I am unsure how to do the same.  I have tried various combinations of

```
[js in Symfony html file]

<script type="text/javascript">
    var v1='{{var1}}';
    var v2='{{var2}}';
    ReactDOM.render(
          {React.createElement(App, {parm1: v1, parm2: v2}, null),
          document.getElementById('root')
        );
</script>
```

But ReactDOM and React are not defined since I am 'outside' of the included compiled react app and thus not accessible (or are they?).

I have been successful with creating a hack by passing via the global window variable but I know there has to be a more appropriate method than this:
(*again {{var1}} and {{var2}} are symfony php variables*)

```
[js in Symfony html file]

<script type="text/javascript">
        var v1 = '{{ var1 }}';
        var v2 = '{{ var2 }}';
        window.passedv1 = v1;
        window.passedv2 = v2;
</script>
```

then accessing inside my React app by:

```
[js in react app]

var v1 = window.passedv1;
var v2 = window.passedv2;
ReactDOM.render(
   <App parm1={v1} parm2={v2} />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Can anyone shed some light on the best way to accomplish this?  I know there has to be a better less-hackish way.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

P.S. I have also passed the parameters by using the data- attributes like this:

**symfony html**

```
<div id="root" data-parm1="val" data-parm2="val"></div>
```

and the accessing inside of my app as:

**index.js**

```
var el = document.getElementById('root');
var v1 = el.getAttribute("data-parm1");
var v2 = el.getAttribute("data-parm2");

ReactDOM.render(
   <App parm1={v1} parm2={v2} />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This works great but I have read in several places that using data- attributes in React is not recommended and frowned upon.

But, there is SO much misinformation and conflicting information about React that sometimes it is hard to know what to heed and what to ignore.

Comment: I have also passed the parameters by using the data- attributes like thus:

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following approach to pass variables to the root component before.

---

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var v1='{{ var1 }}';
            var v2='{{ var2 }}';
            mount(v1, v2)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { App } from './app'

window.mount = function(v1, v2) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App v1={v1} v2={v2} />, document.getElementById('root'))
}
```

---

I'm using ES6 and JSX syntax, but let me know if you want an example without those.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I had not considered accessing it "from the other side".  I like that this exposes/passes the mount function and not the variables.

Comment: I just had another read of my answer and I'm not sure it will actually work in its current state (I was trying to be clever with the parameters). I'll update it later when I'm not on my phone. The concept is the same, only the way props are passed will change.

Comment: I've updated the answer as mentioned in the precious comment